# css @font face not working in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, font-face

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'advertisingmediumregular';
    src: url('fonts/advertisingmedium-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/advertisingmedium-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/advertisingmedium-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/advertisingmedium-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/advertisingmedium-webfont.svg#advertisingmediumregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

the text disappear in google chrome when I wrote this code can anyone help me please

Comment: Do you have an url to the page? It will be much easier for us to help you if we can see more of your code...

Comment: Does it work in another browser? Is it just broken i Chrome?

Comment: yes it works in opera, firfoz and IE

Comment: Do you have an url to the font on fontsquirrel?

Comment: the font name: Advertising Medium

Comment: Couldnt find it, can you provide an url?

Answer (score 0):

I already had the same problem. I was adviced to generate my web fonts with a tool like the [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) webkit fonts generator. Upload your font's files and download back a all browsers compatible pack. Include the css in your HTML page in addition to yours. And it seems to work since I do like this. I hope it will be the same for you.

Comment: I generated web fonts from FontSquirrel and i have this problem